# How to place sub-BeanParam

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jersey, jax-rs, wildfly

I'm using Jax-rs, and there is a method that will receive complex object in its post.

So i tried to make a BeanParam para receiving it.

Here is the service POST method:

```
@POST
public void create(@BeanParam BeanNewPack newPack) {
    newPack.getPacks().stream().forEach(pack::insert);
}
```

In my BeanNewPack I'm placing the fields and annotating with FormParam (as I'm receiving a POST). There is two Long field and one List of another BeanParam that I'm making. Check below:

```
@FormParam("id_from")
private Long idFrom;

@FormParam("id_store")
private Long idStore = -1L;

@FormParam("products_to")
private List<ProductsTo> productsTo;
```

So in my ProductsTo I have the follow fields:

```
@FormParam("id")
private Long id;

@FormParam("amount")
private double amount;

@FormParam("percent")
private double pricePercent;
```

My intent is to post a json like this:

```
{
  "id_from": 1,
  "id_store": -1,
  "products_to": [
    {"id": 2, "amount": 1, "porcent": 0.5},
    {"id": 3, "amount": 1, "porcent": 0.5}
  ]  
}
```

Right now I'm using Wildfly 10, so when I'm tried to deploy the application a get the following erro:

```
11:32:47,881 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./: java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003875: Unable to find a constructor that takes a String param or a valueOf() or fromString() method for javax.ws.rs.FormParam("produtos_para") on private java.util.List ....services.pack.pack.BeanNovoPack.produtosPara for basetype: ....services.pack.servicos.pack.ProdutoPara
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:85)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003875: Unable to find a constructor that takes a String param or a valueOf() or fromString() method for javax.ws.rs.FormParam("produtos_para") on private java.util.List br.com.softbox.ivendas.servicos.pack.BeanNovoPack.produtosPara for basetype: br.com.softbox.ivendas.servicos.pack.ProdutoPara
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.StringParameterInjector.initialize(StringParameterInjector.java:220)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.StringParameterInjector.<init>(StringParameterInjector.java:64)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.FormParamInjector.<init>(FormParamInjector.java:28)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.InjectorFactoryImpl.createParameterExtractor(InjectorFactoryImpl.java:176)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.cdi.CdiInjectorFactory.createParameterExtractor(CdiInjectorFactory.java:124)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.PropertyInjectorImpl.getParameterExtractor(PropertyInjectorImpl.java:118)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.PropertyInjectorImpl.populateMap(PropertyInjectorImpl.java:66)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.PropertyInjectorImpl.<init>(PropertyInjectorImpl.java:54)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.InjectorFactoryImpl.createPropertyInjector(InjectorFactoryImpl.java:65)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.cdi.CdiInjectorFactory.createPropertyInjector(CdiInjectorFactory.java:113)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.FormInjector.<init>(FormInjector.java:37)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.InjectorFactoryImpl.createParameterExtractor(InjectorFactoryImpl.java:119)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.cdi.CdiInjectorFactory.createParameterExtractor(CdiInjectorFactory.java:52)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.<init>(MethodInjectorImpl.java:44)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.InjectorFactoryImpl.createMethodInjector(InjectorFactoryImpl.java:77)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.cdi.CdiInjectorFactory.createMethodInjector(CdiInjectorFactory.java:58)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.<init>(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:99)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.processMethod(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:281)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.register(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:252)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:222)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:194)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:180)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:157)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addPerRequestResource(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:76)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.registration(ResteasyDeployment.java:404)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:245)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.init(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:113)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.init(HttpServletDispatcher.java:36)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:231)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:526)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:101)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
    ... 6 more
```

PS: I've translated the classes names above but not in this last log, I believe there will be no problem to understand, please tell me if so.

What I got it the following:

```
Unable to find a constructor that takes a String param or a valueOf() or fromString() method for javax.ws.rs.FormParam("products_from") on private java.util.List ....services.pack.pack.BeanNewPack.productsTo for basetype: ....services.pack.ProducsTo
```

Is there some way to make a list of BeanParam under another BeanParam?

Answer (score 2):

You don't use `@BeanParam` or `@FormParam` for JSON. If you don't use any annotations and follow the correct JavaBean conventions, you don't need to do anything else. It will automatically get converted for you.

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
public void create(BeanNewPack newPack) {
```

And remove all the `@FormParam`.

If your properties don't follow the JavaBean convention or if you have wierd property names in your JSON that don't map well the the naming convention, then you can use `@JsonProperty`

```
@JsonProperty("id_from")
private Long idFrom;

@JsonProperty("id_store")
private Long idStore = -1L;

@JsonProperty("products_to")
private List<ProductsTo> productsTo;
```

You need to make sure you have Jackson to compile. Jackson is already included in Wildfly, so you can just add it a `provided` dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>2.8.4</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

If you don't want to add any extra dependencies, then you need to follow JavaBean naming convention, e.g.

```
"id_from": 1

// class

public void setId_from() {}
```

It's ugly, I know. But that's what it needs to be if you wan to use underscores in your JSON. There is way you can make the snake-case to camel-case conversion automatic, but that might be out of scope for this question. Just get familiar with using the `@JsonProperty`. If you want o learn more about the automatic conversion, just do a search or post another question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It probably solves the problem, but I still thinking if there is some way to do it with BeanParam or other (JAX-RS) resource without third party libraries.

Comment: As I said in my post: you don't need the library. You only need it if you don't want to use weird property names. As far as BeanParam, it is not for JSON. If you wan to use JSON, then you cant use BeanParam.

Comment: Or just dont use underscores in your JSON. Just use camelcasing